# Callback does not comeback to the Action method

Tags: c#, delegates

I have written something like this:

```
     bool hasChildren = false;
     Action<object> callback = o =>
     {
         if (hasChildren)
         {
           // Do some stuff here.
         }
     };

 base.DoesHaveAnyChildren(callback);
```

and in the base class have defined my method like this:

```
 public bool DoesHaveAnyChildren(Action<object> callback)
 {
      // stuff.
 }
```

So what I want it to do is first go call the `DoesHaveAnyChildren` method and when it is done come back and do the rest of the stuff in that if section.
 **But** it is **NOT** going back to inside that Action part. Why?  What part of syntax and code I got wrong?

Comment: `hasChildren` is statically `false`, so the `if` statement's block will never execute.

Comment: @Servy yes I know. But in this case it is true.

Comment: In this case it's `false`.  It can never, ever be true, because it's statically set to false and no code is ever executed to change it to anything else.  It seems like your example here is too different from your actual code for us to accurately differentiate problems in your example from problems in your real code.  Try to come up with an example that is able to replicate the exact problem you have in your real code, rather than omitting so much.

Comment: @Servy Oh shoot you are right... that is an issue, will fix. But still the main issue is that it does not even hit the break point of this if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually invoke the delegate.

```
public bool DoesHaveAnyChildren(Action<object> callback)
{
    // do some stuff

    //invoke the delegate before returning
    callback(5);
}
```

Your callback doesn't seem to use the `object` argument though, so you might as well use an `Action` (which takes no arguments) instead of an `Action<T>`.

```
 Action callback = () =>
 {
     if (hasChildren)
     {
       // Do some stuff here.
     }
 };

 //call like this
 callback();
```

Comment: where you say "callback(5);"   inside DoesHaveAnyChildren : Well this method is defined inside the base class and callback is inside a method in the child class. I am not sure I understood your answer :(

Comment: @DevWannaBe Your first block of code shows you declared a delegate - when invoked, that delegate will check `if(hasChildren)` and do some other stuff. Then you passed that delegate as an argument to `DoesHaveAnyChildren`. Now, you said you wanted `DoesHaveAnyChildren` to do some stuff and, then, run the code in the delegate, right? To do that, your `DoesHaveAnyChildren` should do whatever it needs to do and invoke the delegate that was passed as a parameter before it returns. The `DoesHaveAnyChildren` doesn't know what `callback` does - it just has to invoke it.

Comment: @DevWannaBe If it's still not clear, could you please explain your doubt? I'm not sure I understood your question either ^^

Comment: I think it is fairly clear. Are you invoking/calling the callback in the `DoesHaveAnyChildren` method or not?